# Using javascript for statement to create a bunch of thumbnail picture links

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript to fill a section of a HTML page with thumbnail images that link to the full sized imagaes. Currently all that happens when this code runs is it prints the p open and close. I want it do make the thumbnails for img (#) where # is 1-41.

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = "<p>"
for( var img = 1; img >= 41; img++)
{
    document.getElementById('img').innerHTML += ("<a href='img/pic (" + img + ").JPG'><img src='img/thumbs/pic (" + img + ").png' width=156 height=84 alt='img " + img + "'></a>")
}
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML += "</p>"
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="img"><div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. <s>Both inside the loop and after it, you're assigning a completely *new* value to the `innerHTML` of the element, overwriting anything you might have had in it before.</s> Apparently after the initial post, you edited the question to use `+=` instead. Even so, using `innerHTML += ...` is a bad idea, as it causes the browser to constantly re-serialize the DOM of the element and re-parse the string each time, and if you hand it half-complete HTML (such as `"<p>"`), what it uses when you do `+=` may well be `"<p></p>"` — and so when you add to it, what you add ends up in the wrong place. Instead, build up the text in a variable and then assign it *once*, at the end.
2. You're starting with `img = 1` and then telling the loop to continue while `img >= 41`. So the loop body is never run, since `1` is not `>= 41`.

Minimal update:

```
var markup = "<p>";
for( var img = 1; img <= 41; img++)
{
    markup += "<a href='img/pic (" + img + ").JPG'><img src='img/thumbs/pic (" + img + ").png' width=156 height=84 alt='img " + img + "'></a>";
}
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = markup + "</p>";
```

Comment: The first statement is incorrect, since OP uses `+=` inside the loop and after it. However, I like your solution, since it does not make DOM lookup multiple times to set `innerHTML`

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as Vadim :)

Comment: actually I edited it after as I had ment to use += origionally it was just = he propobly had the page loaded before I saved the edit

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `for` condition section. Replace

```
for( var img = 1; img >= 41; img++)
```

with

```
for( var img = 1; img <= 41; img++)
```